# Axler 3rd Edition Exercise 6A Problem 26

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

[image]

What is the vector space on which the inner product is defined? and what is the defined inner product for this problem?

My problem is : **here in this problem, the inner product is defined between two functions $f,g$, so the vector space on which this inner product is defined, should be function space**. but, to solve this problem, apparently we need to consider $ R^n $  as the vector space on which usual inner product is defined.

Comment: The inner product is not between two functions, but between two n-dimensional vectors. Indeed, for a fixed t, f(t) and g(t) are vectors, whose usual inner product you need to compute.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentions, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so 
$$\langle f(t), g(t) \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(t)g_i(t)$$
Also, for spaces of functions, only the space of square integrable functions have an inner product structure.